# Connecting to SSH server using Apache mina and public/private keypair

Tags: ssh, apache-mina

I am having trouble connecting to a remote SSH server using Apache Mina.
The server has my public key (in RSA format id_rsa.pub).
I cannot seem to find a way to configure the SshClient to use my private key to make the connection.
The examples I find on the internet are either on how to add KeyAuthentication to the server or using a different key format.

Can anybody steer me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that mina-sshd honours your .ssh/config file, so if that one is setup correctly, it will take care of the keys and jumphost.